# ¿Cómo hacer que las pantallas de React tomen toda la pantalla?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en React para un proyecto anual en la escuela, y llevo varios meses con muchos problemas, entre ellos la pantalla no ocupa todo el contenido.

Lo que ocurre es que de toda la pantalla, la página ocupa la mitad de la misma. Y esto lo sé porque le puse un background-color y este sólo llega hasta la mitad, el resto de la pagina es blanco.

Probé poniendole max-height y height en el index.css del proyecto, ya que estoy usando una StyleSheet que el profesor nos dijo que usaramos, probé poniendole flex: 1 y display: "flex" en el container de la stylesheet, pero no funcionó tampoco

Mi App.js y mi index.css:

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./index.css";
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import LoginForm from "./UI/components/LoginForm"
import { Linking } from "react-native-web";
import AdministrarCurso from "./UI/components/AdministrarCurso";
import AñadirCurso from "./UI/components/AñadirCurso";
import LimpiarCurso from "./UI/components/LimpiarCurso";
import RegisterForm from "./UI/components/RegisterForm";





export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
       <h1> Bienvenido a ClassCleaner.</h1>
      {<LoginForm/>}
      {/*<AdministrarCurso/>*/}
      {/*<LimpiarCurso/>*/}
      {/*<AñadirCurso/>*/}
      {/*<RegisterForm/>*/}
    </View>
  );
}

export const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: "#ADD8E6",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    display: "flex"
  },
});

    body {
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

code {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
}

* {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  max-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: SI estás buscando ponerle estilos globales a la página, ¿por qué no hacerlo desde el archivo `index.html` de la carpeta `public`?

Comment: Creo que lo resolví, al final puse estas lineas de código que encontré en internet, aunque no sé si va a crear algún problema a futuro (y aparte no sé cómo marcar una pregunta cómo respondida aunque nadie la haya respondido):

body > #root > div {
  height: 100vh;
}